# $route.current is undefined when trying to get current params

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to do basic routing in Angular.

My config looks like

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  $routeProvider.when('/', { 
    templateUrl: 'home.html', controller: 'loginCtrl' 
  }, 
  $routeProvider.when('/user_profile/, { 
     templateUrl: 'user_profile.html', controller: 'UserProfileCtrl'
  }
});
```

When I have a link that goes to user_profile I'm unable to get the $route params.

```
<a href="user_profile/?user_id=9">Go To Profile</a>
```

In the controller `$route.params` is `undefined`.

I tried to make a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/J4jJI8mhwWozD9zucJcw?p=preview) but clearly I'm missing something fundamental here

EDIT: `$routeParams`

I have a module that get's the user info from the server. When I pass in `$routeParams` is it set to this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  angular.module('userFromServer', [])
    .service('currentUser', function() {
      <% if logged_in %>
        this.name = '<%= @User.name %>';
        this.id = '<%= @User.id %>'
      <% else %>
        this.name, this.id = '';
      <% end %>
    })
</script>
```

Comment: try $routeParams.user_id... assuming that you are injecting them to controller and you route looks like $routeProvider.when('/user_profile/:user_id, { 
     templateUrl: 'user_profile.html', controller: 'UserProfileCtrl'
  }

Comment: Your config doesn't look like valid javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this

You can use `$routeParams` for getting the routing parameteres

**[Plunker (Non HTML5 Mode)](http://plnkr.co/edit/PRlz2JKne0oFzcoBXLo4?p=preview)**

**[Plunker (HTML5 Mode)](http://plnkr.co/edit/RmGwAnsOJeaaq9emWBHl?p=preview)**

```
app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

  $routeProvider.when('/', { 
    templateUrl: 'home.html', 
    controller: 'loginCtrl' 
  })
  .when('/user_profile/:user_id', { 
     templateUrl: 'user_profile.html', 
     controller: 'UserProfileCtrl'
  });

});  

app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams) {
  $scope.name = "Hello"
  console.log($routeParams); 
}); 

app.controller('UserProfileCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams) {
  $scope.name = "UserProfile"
  console.log($routeParams); 
});
```

Comment: that looks good except that it doesn't use html5mode(true). I [tried](http://plnkr.co/edit/B5p25gwyzbAE2pzj670W?p=preview) to enable html5mode but I got the same result as my plunkr. Can you make this work for html5 mode?

Comment: @user2954587 Take a look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RmGwAnsOJeaaq9emWBHl?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

YOu need $route as a parameter in your controller.

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($route) {
```

Comment: yeah, that's not the issue though

Comment: That resolved my problem similar to this, so have an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

try to get it from

```
$routeParams.user_id
```

... assuming that you are injecting them to controller and you route looks something like this

```
$routeProvider.when('/user_profile/:user_id, { 
    templateUrl: 'user_profile.html', 
    controller: 'UserProfileCtrl'
}
```

Comment: interesting, it seems like $routeParams is override by my `userFromServer` module

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but maybe my solution can still help people.

If your HTML document has a title element in the head element
$Route does not work as expected.

Rather set ALL the Application title's in the app.config function.

Comment: try to highlight the keywords and be clear with the format it will help to reach out your answer for others

Answer (score -1):

From the documentation:

> Note that the $routeParams are only updated after a route change completes successfully. This means that you cannot rely on $routeParams being correct in route resolve functions. Instead you can use $route.current.params to access the new route's parameters.

Comment: Not if $route.current is undefined, as the question states it is